# Am I required to provide for my abusive parents' life after I move out?

Tags: india, family-law, children, parental-rights, compensation

#### Background

My mother died 12 years ago when I was 8 years old and my drunkard father (F) married someone else (step-mother, SM) to help him raise me. Past decade has been a disaster for me. I was constantly wrongfully portrayed as a thief, a liar etc. I was also blamed for the beatings bestowed by F onto the SM, but it was their behaviour the whole time, and I was the scapegoat. It was proved when I moved to college and they kept fighting.

#### Problem

I feel no love towards them and want to move out soon after graduation. I know that I am happier when I stay away from them. I wish I could sue them, but that could drag for a long time. So cutting off all ties sounds like a better idea.

But the other day SM was blabbering something to the effect of "government will require you to pay for my life when I grow old and you start earning". Is there a process in place where people can demand their unwilling children to provide for themselves? I don't mind doing that as long as I want to. But can something force me to do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like the answer is yes. There was a bill passed around 2007 called the "Maintenance and Welfare of Parents and Senior Citizens Act, 2007". You should track down official information as I am going by newspaper articles. If an employed, adult child isn't supporting their parents or step-parents, 60 or older, their parents or step-parents can go to a tribunal and ask for an enforcement order. The upper limit was 10000 rupees per month or a possible jail term.

The [Times of India has an article](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/children-in-law-will-also-be-responsible-for-care-of-aged/articleshow/72375817.cms) from December 2019 that the government plans to expand the law to include son- and daughter-in-laws as responsible besides children, step-children, and adoptive children. The new bill also includes grandparents and they  do not have to be over 60. The plan is also to remove the 10000 cap.

Comment: #ThirdWorldProblems

Comment: @Studoku At least one Canadian province has legislation about supporting parents. I know someone who wrote a law thesis on it.